# Remove xml character in python

Tags: python, xml, csv

I have the following code, which takes information from an XML file and saves some data in a csv file.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

title = []
category = []
url = []
prod = []

def find_title():
    for t in root.findall('solution/head'):
        title.append(t.find('title').text)

    for c in root.findall('solution/body'):
        category.append(c.find('category').text)

    for u in root.findall('solution/body'):
        url.append(u.find('video').text)

    for p in root.findall('solution/body'):
        prod.append(p.find('product').text)

find_title()

headers = ['Title', 'Category', 'Video URL','Product']

def save_csv():
    with open('titles.csv', 'w') as f:
        f_csv = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\r')
        f_csv.writerow(headers)
        f.write(''.join('{},{},{},{}\n'.format(title, category, url, prod) for title, category, url, prod in zip(title, category, url, prod)))

save_csv()
```

I have found an issue with the text that contains ',' because it separates the output save in the list e.g:

```
<title>Add, Change, or Remove Transitions between Slides</title>
```

is getting save in the list as [Add, Change, or Remove Transitions between Slides] which make sense since this is a csv file, however, I would like to keep the whole output together.

So I there any way to remove the ',' from the title tag or can I add more code to override the ','

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you want to keep comma, you'll get in trouble with CSV; but if it's possible to replace commas with something else (like character `-`), do it with string replacement.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasimazar No, CSV files can handle commas when quoted properly. The `cvs` module  does that by default. [Edit:] And is being used properly (no direct writing to the file).

Comment: Why are you using `csv.writerow` for the headers but not for the data rows? If you use it for the data rows it will handle the quoting/special character issues for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear why you're writing the row data with a `file.write()` call rather than using the csv writer's `writerow` method (which you are using for the header row. Using that method will take care of quoting / special character issues wrt. data containing quotes and commas.

Change:

```
f.write(''.join('{},{},{},{}\n'.format(title, category, url, prod) for title, category, url, prod in zip(title, category, url, prod)))
```

to:

```
for row in zip(title, category, url, prod):
    f_csv.writerow(row)
```

and your CSV should work as expected, assuming your CSV reader handles the quoted fields.

Comment: this is the first time I work with XML and CSV files, thanks for the heads up. I did change the line and work perfectly.

Comment: Cool. Incidentlaly, in your original code, you have `lineterminator='\r'` when you create the CSV writer, but then your manual line-writes werre adding `'\n'`. It's not clear which you actually want but with this code you'll get `'\r'` line endings.

Comment: Which is fairly unusual (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). If in doubt I'd omit the lineterminator param entirely and let it use the default CSV dialect

Comment: great, understood and thanks for information, really appreciate your feedback